# Where does this proof of Cayley Menger determinant use planarity?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, determinant, simplex

Terence Tao gives, as ever, a wonderfully streamlined proof of the Cayley-Menger determinant's (for the case of a tetrahedron) vanishing on 4 planar points [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/05/25/the-spherical-cayley-menger-determinant-and-the-radius-of-the-earth/), at the very beginning of the article.

I quite liked it until I realised I had no idea *quite where the proof used the assumption that the points all lay on a plane*. It seems to me that the distances argument using the cosine rule hidden in the dot product would work for two vectors in 3D space so that $|AB|^2=|A|^2+|B|^2-2A\cdot B$ was true for any two points $A,B$ and then the factorisation works also.

**Where is this assumption used?**

(Furthermore, it seems that his factorisation of what he calls $G$ into $\Sigma\Sigma^{T}$ where $\Sigma$ is a $5\times 2$ matrix in fact gives a factorisation of $2G$, though this is less important.)

Comment: I don't see why it should be $2G $.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Thanks - it turns out my confusion and this problem were one and the same, as shown by the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used when noting that $\Sigma$ is a $5 \times 2$ matrix (and hence has rank at most 2): what this matrix actually is is the vectors stacked together, i.e. if $A=(a_1,a_2)$ and so on, it's
$$ \Sigma = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ a_1 & a_2 \\ b_1 & b_2 \\ c_1 & c_2 \\ d_1 & d_2 \end{pmatrix} . $$
Were we considering vectors in (say) 3 dimensions, the matrix $\Sigma$ would instead have rows $(a_1 , a_2, a_3)$ etc., so the rank cannot be bounded above by 2 any more and we can't do the $1+1+2 < 5$ part of the calculation that shows the rank is not $5$.

Comment: Thank you, wonderfully explained (in a way which also makes it clear how to generalise the proof for $n$ dimensions).